# Images loaded from the iOS Camera Roll have a bad quality when they are presented in a second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have written an App which shows all images from the camera roll in a collection view. When the user taps on a cell a second view controller is shown with the selected Image. My problem is that the bigger image on the second view controller has a bad quality.

Thats the code for getting the images:

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

func grabPhotos() {



    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    if fetchResult.count > 0 {


        for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {

            imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {

                image, error in

                self.imageArray.append(image!)

            })

        }


    } else {

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }


}
```

And here I´m passing the image to the second view controller:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    imageThatWillBePassed = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Show Image", sender: self)

}
```

Code to show the image:

```
class ShowImageViewController: UIViewController {

var imgToPass = UIImage()

@IBOutlet weak var imageToShow: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var backBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var shareBtn: UIBarButtonItem!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    imageToShow.image = imgToPass
}
```

I think the problem is that I´m passing the image with the quality of the actual cell but I don't know how to fix that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You left out the important code - show how you display the image.

Comment: `targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)` seems to be the culprit...

Comment: Ok, I´ve added the code

Comment: When I´m changing the target size the app is crashing

Comment: Why it it crashing if you change the `targetSize:`? What's the error? I'd suggest that you keep `PHAsset` object in your array, call the `imgManager.requestImage` stuff in your `UICollectionViewCell`, pass the `PHAsset` to your next `UIViewController` that will show with a bigger `targetSize:`.